# Distance between a line segment and a Cuboid

Tags: geometry, vectors, 3d, solid-geometry

Given a cuboid ABCD.EFGH. What is the shortest distance $d$ between the cuboid and the line segment $\overline{V1V2}$?

[Illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HM7U0.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Sam, I can find the distance d2 (see Figure) between the line segment and the vertices. Also, I can find the distance between V1V2 and AC or AB... 
I need to find the distance between  Cuboid face.

Comment: Not enough information is given. The only answer that can be given is that (of course if the segment doesn't intersect the cuboïd) depending on the cases, the smallest distance is achieved by a point situated on the surface, on the edges or on a vertex of the cuboid.  **I would advise you to treat first a simpler problem : smallest distance of a planar segment to a rectangle.**